# Optimize Magento code : taking too much time to load data using google API and Magento collection

Tags: magento-enterprise, mysql, google-api

I am using Google location (longitude/latitude api) to search location based on user input (longitude/latitude,country,city,location_id) so for that first I am loading Magento collection and iterating collection data and based on data i am sending request to google Api.
But it is taking too time to get result (around 15-20 sec).

```
$mapviewCollection = Mage::getModel("location/store")->getCollection();
            if (isset($country_id) && $country_id !== 'NULL') {
                $mapviewCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',    $country_id);
            }
            if (isset($city_id) && $city_id !== 'NULL') {
                $mapviewCollection->addFieldToFilter('city_id', $city_id);
            }
            if (isset($location_id) && $location_id !== 'NULL') {
                $mapviewCollection->addFieldToFilter('location_id', $location_id);
            }
            if (isset($brand_id) && $brand_id !== 'NULL') {
                $mapviewCollection->addFieldToFilter('id', $brand_id);
            }

        /* mapview of store within selected Kilometers */

        if (isset($area_km) && $area_km !== 'NULL') {

    $mapviewCollection->addFieldToSelect(array('id','store_name','latitude','longitude' ));
            $mapviews = $mapviewCollection->getData();

            if ($mapviews) {
                foreach ($mapviews as $mapview) {

                    if ($mapview['latitude'] != null && $mapview['longitude'] != null) {

                        $source = $latitude . ',' . $longitude;
                        $destination = $mapview['latitude'] . ',' . $mapview['longitude'];

                        $apikey = Mage::getStoreConfig('testapi/testapi_group/google_mapapi_key');
                        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" . $source . "&destinations=" . $destination . "&mode=driving&language=en-US&key=" . $apikey;

                        $string = file_get_contents($url);
                        $json_a = json_decode($string, TRUE);
                        $distance = $json_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']; // distance in meters km = m / 1000.0
                        $distance = (float) ($distance / 1000);
                        if ($distance <= $area_km) {
                            $mapviewarr['test_id'] = $mapview['id'];
                            $mapviewarr['test_name'] = Mage::helper('mobileapi')->translate($mapview['store_name'], $locale);
                            $mapviewarr['latitude'] = $mapview['latitude'];
                            $mapviewarr['longitude'] = $mapview['longitude'];
                            $data[] = $mapviewarr;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have tried by writing simple mysql query also and found no change. Seems the time it is taking because of foreach loop. 
Please help me how i can decrease the response time for time. Please give your suggestion ASAP.

Comment: How many stores are there?

Comment: @smartie In database i have 657 stores. But while fetching 3-4 will come as a result. Actually the issue is not while fetching from DB,the issue is with foreach loop because for each found record i am sending request to google Api.

Answer (score 1):

You have kind of answered your own question in your comment.

Relying on a third party service is always going to be a bottle neck and further more, you have very little control over it.

Although you might only have 3 or 4 results at the end, this is being deduced from the result of the google api (mostly). If i was in this situation i would be looking to reduce the number of results i need to look up using the api (in your mapviewCollection result).

Basically i would try and use the google api as little as possible.